# Unable to test Azure SAML Single SignOn application

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I have configured the on-premise application with the **Application proxy connector**.

I have followed all the steps mentioned in the below article, and they are working fine. I'm able to login to the **External URL** with the user assigned to the application and able to access the on-premise application remotely.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy-add-on-premises-application

I'm facing an issue when I click on the **Test** button in **Test single sign-on with Test App Name** section in **Single Sign-on**.

I have followed below steps:

1. **Application proxy** configured in on-premise windows server and registered on-premise application
   under  **Enterprise applications** in Azure portal AAD.
2. When I go to a particular on-premise application under **Enterprise
   application**s and clicked on **Single Sign-on --> SAML** . Here all config
   are loaded by default.
3. I moved to the last section, **Test single sign-on with Test App Name**, and clicked on **Test**,
   it has thrown below error.

> This functionality is not enabled or not available.

How to resolve above issue.

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try assign different users to that enterprise application. After assigning kindly try Testing single sign-on. Check whether that is user is the Azure AD account user.

Also check in Azure active directory -select the user - select profile - settings - Block sign-in - No

Check whether the user license is assigned and which license the user is currently assigned.

kindly try this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/application-proxy-configure-single-sign-on-on-premises-apps) and check it.

Kindly let me know if you have any further queries.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. Let me verify on that. Could you please look into the below query aswell. Facing issue while reading claims. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63895561/how-to-get-claims-from-azure-saml-sso-token